# C PROGRAMMING: Storing and classifying strings into an array from a text file

Tags: c

Basically what I'm trying to do is read differential equations from a text file, then classifying them by the apostrophes (' is first order) ('' is second order) and then storing each equation into an array which I can then print if they are first or 2nd order. It says I have no errors but when I run it, my compiler crashes. what did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fin;
    int i;
    char line[300];
    int value = 0;
    fin = fopen("DIFFERNTIAL_EQNS.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fin) != EOF)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        if (line[i] == ('\''))
        {
            if (line[i++] == ('\''))
            {
                value = 2;
            }
            value = 1;
        }
    }

    if (value == 1)
        printf("this is 1st order\n");
    else
        printf("this is 2nd order\n");

    fclose(fin);
}
```

Comment: _I have no errors but when I run it, my compiler crashes._ ......o.O...

Comment: First thing: check the `fopen` return value. It can fail.

Comment: @LPs an interesting confusion of ideas/terms I guess ^^ I would recommend OP to use a debugger to find out which line exactly causes the crash

Comment: oh forgot to put the text file in the project folder, but now that I did, when I run it the compiler is just black and nothing else?? uhhh

Comment: The compiler will have finished its work before you can run the program, so it's hard to tell what you're talking about.

Comment: Please stop saying "the compiler", the compiler is the program that turns your C code into executable machine instructions, it is not doing anything when you are running the code. And if you get no output then there is most likely something wrong with your logic. The first step to figuring that out would be to attach a debugger to your executable (or at least add more `printf` statements in relevant positions to see which code is executed and which isn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

I think this line is a problem:

```
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fin) != EOF)
```

`fgets` doesn't return `EOF`. It returns a `NULL` when done (or on error).

So try:

```
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fin) != NULL)
```

or just

```
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fin))
```

Further, this line is bad:

```
for (i = 0; i < 300; i++)
```

You can't be sure that `fgets` filled the whole line array. Instead do:

```
for (i = 0; line[i]; i++)   // or for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

so that you only continue until the zero-termination.

The you have a bug here:

```
    if (line[i] == ('\''))
    {
        if (line[i++] == ('\''))  <---- use +1 instead
        {
            value = 2;
        }
        value = 1;  // <------ You always overwrite with 1 so you never get 2
    }
```

Instead do:

```
    if (line[i] == ('\''))
    {
        value = 1;
        if (line[i+1] == ('\''))
        {
            value = 2;
        }
     }
```

Also it seems your code can only handle one line as you just overwrite `value` in each loop. Maybe you want to put the print inside the loop. Like:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fin))
{
    for (i = 0; line[i]; i++)
        if (line[i] == ('\''))
        {
            value = 1;
            if (line[i+1] == ('\''))
            {
                value = 2;
            }
        }

    // Print the result for this line before reading next line
    if (value == 1)
        printf("this is 1st order\n");
    else if (value == 2)
        printf("this is 2nd order\n");
    else
        printf("Didn't find anything\n");

    value = 0;
}


fclose(fin);
```

Then another problem - consider the input:

> x'' + 3x' + x

The code above will say it is 1st order because the `3x'` will "overwrite" value to 1. So you need to make sure not go from 2 back to one. Maybe like:

```
    if (line[i] == ('\''))
    {
        if (value == 0) value = 1;  // Changed this
        if (line[i+1] == ('\''))
        {
            value = 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: wow I really appreciate the time you took to help me out. and trust me it sure was helpful. I assume that you meant else if (value == 2)
        printf("this is 2nd order\n"); instead of ==1. do you know how to print two ' in a row without getting a quotation error. example: if (line[i+1] == ('\''')) or would I have to do ('\'\'')

Comment: Correct - `value == 2` :-) Copy-and-paste with no edit.... About the question in the comment: Can't you just use: `printf("\'\'\n");` ? That works for me. But maybe you are not talking about printing...?

Comment: oh yeah I am, okay that works. so there is something with this code that isn't totally right. see what I'm trying to do is make it go through every line and identify if its first or second order, then assign the value. here is how I attempted it right now  `while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fin))
 {
  for (i = 0; line[i]; i++)
   if (line[i] == ('\'' && '\'\''))
    value = 2;
   else
    value = 1;
  if (line[i + 1] == ('\''))
   value = 1;
 }`

Comment: @nicolepanda `(line[i] == ('\'' && '\'\''))` is illegal. You just can't do that. Why not use the answer as it is? Any problems?

Comment: @nicolepanda - you can do:         `if (line[i] == ('\'') && line[i+1] == ('\'')) { value=2;} else if (line[i] == ('\'')) {value = 1;}` but I see no reason for that.

Comment: @nicolepanda - I spotted another problem - see updated answer.

Comment: perfectly done @4386427, respect a lot. when I run this program it only prints the first array, how do I make it print more than one? like I have 2 equations to test

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because fopen is not finding the file, almost certainly. (If you run through a debugger, the start or home directory may not be the one you think it is). However there's also a bug. Generally if you use a for loop, you should not increment the counter within the loop body. Also, you should break on line[i] == 0, or you will read random garbage after the string end.

Comment: that was indeed the problem, but now that I covered it, when I run the program the compiler is just pitch black with no text at all. I'm not even entirely sure if I coded this correctly now.

Comment: So print out "hello" to ensure that you have output. Then print out each line of the file, and other diagnostics, like "value".

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` does not return a character as other input functions do, rather it returns either the pointer to the string on success, or `NULL`. *`NULL` is something very different from `EOF`!* As such, the comparison to `EOF` always yields false, so that the `while()` loop cannot be left (I guess, your program just freezes).

To fix this, just compare the result of `fgets()` to `NULL` or just write

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fin)) {
```

as `NULL` is always interpreted as a false value.

---

Btw: I see three more errors in your program:

- You overrun the line strings that are returned by `fgets()` by failing to check for the terminating zero byte. This can easily lead to false classifications of your strings.
- You don't allow for arbitrarily long lines. If I were you, I would use `getline()` instead of `fgets()`: It will automatically allocate a buffer to fit the line, allowing you to correctly handle input of any length.
- `i++` increments the value *after* using it. Accordingly, your two `if(line[...] == ('\''))` statements either fire both or none because they check the same character.